# How do I add a link to a stack/bundle using the Delicious API?

Tags: delicious-api

So, I've create a link with tag "test" on Delicious. Now I want to add the link to my "TestStack" stack/bundle/whatever using the Delicious API.

The [documentation](http://delicious.com/developers) says you can do so using https://api.del.icio.us/v1/tags/bundles/set?:

> Assign a set of tags to a single bundle, wipes away previous settings for bundle.

Okay, super. I tried this using cURL and the Ruby API; nothing happens, nothing at all. My links with tag "test" are still floating around, assigned to no bundles/stacks.

```
curl -u username:password "https://api.del.icio.us/v1/tags/bundles/set?bundle=TestStack&tags=test"
```

Any ideas how to make this work? Maybe this API method is meant for something different?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Delicious does not yet have support for assigning links to stacks/bundles via their API (I talked with them directly). However, you CAN create new links and assign them to stacks/bundles via email. From https://delicious.com/settings#mobile:

> When you save a single link, you can also add comments, tags, set the
>   privacy and add the link to a stack by using C:, T:, P: and S: in the
>   email body. The subject field will be the Title of the link.

```
For example: 
Subject: A cool link
http://mycoollink.com/
C: I love this link
T: cool links, my link
P: No
S: Cool Links
```